# Project Job Scheduling: Where are resetPanel and createChart called?

Tags: optaplanner

I am working on a Class that takes data from a csv, works with a Scheduler Object, and associates the data with the scheduler's attributes(Project, Job, Allocation, Resource, etc). I was thinking after I got everything down(ProjectList, JobList, AllocationList, ExecutionModeList, Resources) I could just pass the scheduler object into createChart.

However, I am still unsure as to where resetPanel and createChart are called( I understand that the ProjectJobPanel has these functions).

So my 2 questions are:

1. Where are these functions called?( I couldn't find this information in the documentation)
2. If i want to display my data, do I need to do anything else other than pass in the scheduler object into the "createChart" function?

Comment: Use "find usages" in your IDE and you 'll [find this](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/common/swingui/SolverAndPersistenceFrame.java#L664).

Answer (score 0):

`resetPanel()` is called by the example swing dialog when a new dataset is loaded. If `updatePanel()` isn't overwritten, it's also called when a new best solution is found (so for every best solution changed event).